# Connecting USB external hard drive to a server in a datacenter - how to ensure that it works?

Tags: windows, usb-drive, ntfs, external-hdd, exfat

I've bought a pair of Seagate Expansion 4TB 2.5" drives, with the intention of posting them to my webhost (Hetzner in Germany) for them to connect so I can use them as bandwidth rather than try to download 8TB of data over my home internet connection.

At home I have a macbook and a pair of Windows 10 machines.  The server is CentOS 7.

The HDDs claim Windows and Mac compatibility but don't mention Linux.  I'm assuming once plugged in I'll be able to get them working via various package installs.  But since they'll be 1000 miles from me, I want to check to see if there's anything I can do to increase the chances of them working.

I'd probably rather use exFAT or NTFS so they work on my Windows PC when they get back, but I imagine I can find a driver that'll allow ext4 in Windows if I search around?

Any tips?  Or is the answer "it's just a USB drive, it'll work, just get them in the post already".

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the answer *is* actually "it's just a USB drive". You are right about filesystem concerns, I think CentOS 7 does *not* provide drivers for *exFAT* by default. If possible, check with them which file system drivers they provide.

Comment: It's a dedicated server, so I can install anything I want.  I've installed (I think) exFAT and NTFS drivers but can't test them in anyway until they get the drives.  Given that I'm sending two drives and this will be a recurrent operation every month or so my plan is to send one of each this time around and see if one gets on better than the other... BUT, I guess actually once they're connected so long as the USB drivers work correctly I can reformat the drives as I wish, so it makes no difference really.  I think.

Comment: If you have admin access, then you can install NTFS support from the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repositories which still belong to the "RedHat family" (you can get an overview [here](https://centos.pkgs.org/). exFAT support only seems to be available via 3rd-party repositories that are "further away" from CentOS.

Comment: Thanks @AdminBee - useful knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the drives I suggest you fire up a VM on either your Mac or Windows machine, install CentOS 7 in the VM and then attach the USB drives to the VM.

This will

1. Let you work out what filesystems you can install on CentOS (and work out what you need to do to install/configure them before you start messing with a remote machine)
2. Test that data written to the disks can then be read from OSx/Windows when you get the drives back

Comment: A good suggestion, and one that I knew I should do before I asked this question.  I was being lazy I guess.